How to create third party settings for themes?
How to I properly implement third party settings for a theme, without clearing 3rd party settings from other modules?
E.g. my site has a gin.settings.yml with
third_party_settings:
  shortcut:
    module_link: true

Now I install my module, which implements hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter :
function tailwind_jit_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id = NULL) {
  $form['third_party_settings']['tailwind_jit'] = [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#open' => TRUE,
    '#title' => t('Tailwind CSS Just-in-time compilation'),
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#parents' => ['third_party_settings', 'tailwind_jit'],
  ];
  $form['third_party_settings']['tailwind_jit']['compile_html_requests'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Compile HTML requests'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('third_party_settings.tailwind_jit.compile_html_requests', $themeToBeConfigured),
  ];
}

This works and saves my config settings BUT it also wipes the pre-existing shortcut.module_link setting from shortcut module, leading to a config like
# shortcut settings are now missing
third_party_settings:
  tailwind_jit:
    compile_html_requests: 1

How to I properly implement 3rd party settings in hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter?

This might be a known bug as in https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3087036 , but I'm not really sure if this is really the same problem

TL,DR: This sucks :((( Issue #3087036 is the root problem, but then #3402885 made it even worse and finally contrib like Gin copied the bug now into their own code base, making it currently more or less impossible to use 3rd party settings in themes. I start to hate config inspector.

I have been able to solve the same problem by saving the value of my modifications with configFactory:
**
 * Implements hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter
 */
function bootstrap_toolbox_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id = NULL){
  $theme = $form_state->getBuildInfo()['args'][0];
  $utilityService = \Drupal::service('bootstrap_toolbox.utility_service');
  
  $form['third_party_settings']['bootstrap_toolbox'] = [
    '#type' => 'details',
    '#title' => t('Bootstrap Toolbox settings'),
  ];
  $form['third_party_settings']['bootstrap_toolbox']['base_theme'] = [
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Behavior settings'),
    '#options' => $utilityService->getBaseThemes(),
    '#empty_options' => 'none',
    '#default_value' => \Drupal::configFactory()
      ->get("{$theme}.settings")
      ->get('third_party_settings')['bootstrap_toolbox']['base_theme'],
  ];

  // Get a different result!
  // with kint(theme_get_setting('third_party_settings')) I get:
  // third_party_settings:
  //   shortcut:
  //     module_link: true ;

  $form['#submit'][] = 'bootstrap_toolbox_theme_settings_submit';
  
}

function bootstrap_toolbox_theme_settings_submit($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state){
  $theme = $form_state->getBuildInfo()['args'][0];
  \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable("{$theme}.settings")
      ->set('third_party_settings.bootstrap_toolbox.base_theme', $form_state->getValue('base_theme'))
      ->save(TRUE);
}

